# Programmatically convert ready -> draft GitHub PR or vice versa

Tags: api, github

Does anyone know how to convert a GitHub PR that is ready to a draft PR and vice versa programmatically? I am trying with the v3 ReST API and the v4 GraphQL api. I can change properties like title and body just fine in both APIs, but when I try to change the draft field, it's not supported. It's also not mentioned in the docs. Somehow it must be possible, at least the GitHub web UI has buttons to do just that, in both directions, but it's not calling either API, but backend functions that have nothing to do with the v3/v4 APIs.